# Morphophonemic rule formulation

Tags: phonology, morphology

Can someone help me to translate this morphophonemic rule?

```
V ⇒ ∅ / C ___ + V
```

> Vowels become null in the environment ...

What is "...", i.e., what is the environment translated into English?

Comment: A vowel deletes if it is simultaneously preceded by a consonant, and followed by a heteromorphemic vowel.

Comment: The rule into English. The second part is what I can't translate after '/' or 'in the environment'.

Comment: What does "+" mean?

Comment: V = vowel
⇒ = become
∅ = null
/ = in the environment
C = consonant
__ = before
+ = ??
V = vowel
Does anyone know what does '+' stand for?

Comment: @Pearl Morpheme boundary. *+ V* means there is a vowel in another morpheme which succeeds the morpheme were the deleted vowel occurs.

Comment: The symbol + in the context means sandhi (internal or external) or a morpheme boundary.

Answer (score 4):

Your first part is correct, but I'm going to go through the whole translation for completeness.

```
V ⇒ ∅ / C ___ + V
```

Breaking this down into parts:

```
V
```

Standard shorthand for "any vowel", or sometimes "any short vowel".

```
⇒
```

"Becomes".

```
∅
```

"Null", that is, the sound disappears entirely.

```
/
```

"When" or "in the following environment".

```
C ___ + V
```

This is the environment in which the change happens:

> ```
> C
> ```
>
> Standard shorthand for "any consonant".
>
> ```
> ___
> ```
>
> This is where the sound being modified appears.
>
> ```
> +
> ```
>
> This is the rarest symbol in this rule. `+` indicates a boundary between two morphemes, such as a stem and a suffix.
>
> ```
> V
> ```
>
> Another vowel.

So all together, the translation would be:

> A vowel becomes null when it's preceded by a consonant, and followed by a morpheme break, and then a vowel.

Comment: In what way is + "rarest"? Compared to what? (Specifically, why is Ø not rarer?)

Comment: @user6726 Just in the informal sense that I've seen Ø more often than + in these rules. I'm guessing it was the one OP was having difficulty with, since they got the first part on their own.